# PHP : How to ensure script does not fail if method does not exist?

Tags: php, class, methods

I have a PHP script which calls methods from a class I have written. However due to the nature of the system there are occasions where the method called does not exist e.g

```
$snippets = new Snippets();

echo $snippets->fakeMethod();
```

in the above example `fakeMethod()` does not exist and the script fails with a fatal error and stops altogether.

I need a solution whereby **either** the method just fails silently or the method is checked against all methods in the class first using `method_exists()` however I cannot put if statements in the script e.g.

```
if(method_exists(fakemethod, snippets)){ 

echo $snippets->fakeMethod();

}
```

instead the "work" needs to be done in the class somehow. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a "magic" [method `__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)

Comment: this looks awesome. Just a quick thought, is there a PHP 4 equivalent?

Comment: No, there is not. btw: why on Earth are you using PHP4?

Comment: I'm not fortunately -  however the system I'm developing may be deployed on a PHP4 server at some point - hopefully not....

Comment: If your hosting company has still php4 then just leave them

Answer (score 1):

See: [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)